# App to shut down iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, applications, power

Is there an app to shut down my iPhone 3G? It's a non jailbroken iPhone and the power button isn't working anymore. So I need to shut it down with an app. Any advice?

Comment: Can you play music or video content until it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this will help. I had the same problem with a 3G. I found if you squeeze the front and back of the phone, just at the on/off button whilst pressing the on/off button, then it would all work fine.  It's as if there's just a connection that's slightly come apart, which squeezing reconnects. Kept me going for months, as I waited for the 4S! Good luck.

Comment: Allright thanks. Yep, it just till my 4S arrives. It should be within 2 days :-)

Answer (score 2):

Apps aren't allowed to access this functionality so there is no way to get this without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 0):

Challenge accepted. The best app(lication) for the job would be to let the battery run out. Problem solved. Rejoice!